# Is there a way to look at a flat file (TXT or CSV) and determine information like line endings and delimiters in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to write a Powershell script that takes a flat file (txt or csv), and spits out various information on the file itself. Things like row/column delimiters, data types, rowcount etc.

Rowcount and data types is easy, but I'm not sure on delimiters. Is there anything inbuilt in Powershell that can return this info?

Comment: Note that csv data can contain line breaks if the value is quoted, so you can’t just count the number of lines in the file to get the row count - you need to parse the data, and *that* depends on knowing the delimiter… (unless you can *safely* assume your specific file has no line breaks in the data)

Comment: `(get-content file) -replace '\r','\r' -replace '\n','\n'`